# AS3Crypto & CryptoPP Rijndael ECB

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, encryption, aes, crypto++

I'm wondering how you would code your AS3 decryption method if I use this CryptoPP function to encrypt the data:

```
std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key, const std::string& iv)
{
std::string str_out;
CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::Rijndael>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());

CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
    new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
            false // do not append a newline
        ),
        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING
    )
);
return str_out;
}
```

What I have here gives me the first several characters of the original text and ending with some random bytes.

```
var type = "aes-128-ecb";  // I've tried aes, aes-128-ecb
var key = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString("xxxxxxxxxxxxx"));

function decryptByteArray(data:ByteArray):String
{
    //var data:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(txt);
    var pad:IPad = new NullPad();  // i've also tried PKCS5
    var mode:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher(type, key, pad);
    var ivmode:IVMode = mode as IVMode;
    ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(""));
    pad.setBlockSize(mode.getBlockSize());
    mode.decrypt(data);
    return Hex.toString(Hex.fromArray(data));
}
```

I've also tried PKCS5 as padding method but gets this error:

```
Error: PKCS#5:unpad: Invalid padding value. expected [166], found [229]
at com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric::PKCS5/unpad()
at com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric::CBCMode/decrypt()
at DecryptionTestAS3Crypto_fla::MainTimeline/decryptByteArray()
at DecryptionTestAS3Crypto_fla::MainTimeline/loaderComplete()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Not sure what's wrong here.  Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: The Crypto++ looks OK. `NullPad` looks wrong since the block must be padded. `IV` looks wrong because the `ECB` mode does not use an `IV`. You might also verify `data:ByteArray` is *not* `Base64`.